# How to temporarily Disable a SharePoint Site

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365

I faced a quite interesting situation today where I wanted to put my SharePoint side down, I mean I wanted to stop users from accessing it apart from the site collection admin. Removing User's permission was a straight forward approach but my site had 100+ groups and I'll need to reconfigure them again after the downtime.

So I wanted to know if there's anyway to make a SharePoint Unavailable for a specific period. I am currently using Office 365 though tips for SharePoint 2013 on premise would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Set-SPOSite, you can lock down the Office 365 site collection with the LockState parameter.

```
Set-SPOSite -Identity https://contoso.sharepoint.com -LockState NoAccess
```

Optionally, Set-SPOTenant can be used to redirect users from the locked site to another location.

```
Set-SPOTenant -NoAcessRedirectUrl 'http://www.contoso.com'
```

For SharePoint On-Prem

```
Set-SPSite -Identity "" -LockState ""
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably late, but editing the permission levels on the site might be easier than removing users access, and your SC admins will still have access.

Answer (score -1):

Stop the webapplication process from Inetmgr

Regard
Arjun

Comment: I appreciate your response though stopping an application pool process would disable all the sites in the webapp. Also I am using office 365.

Comment: then i think you dont have any other go since you want the site to be accessed by the site collection admins